# Using Jquery UI plugin with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I wanted to use the jquery's UI layout plugin in an angular application. Is there an angular directive that does this already, or serves the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngularJS` is here to be built for robust arhitecture and that is why we see so many modules in terms of directives and other components. Putting `JQuery` with it will be like going away from their core design and you will yourself end up in a mess maintaining the codebase.

**jQuery is a crutch if you are writing AngularJS applications.**

If you’re starting an `AngularJS` app, take a good look at [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp). Then take a look at [ui-bootstrap’s directives](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src). They are a living example of how you can do “jQuery things” with a fraction of the code, and build an app that is easier to maintain, way more testable, and generally nicer to work with.

Take a look at this stuff

- **[How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)** - An excellent Stack Overflow post that expands on this viewpoint
- [**Using AngularJS? Then stop using jQuery**](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/)

Comment: Is it okay to use Angular's Jquery Passthrough as in http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq if using the plugin was a must for me .

Comment: If you are using jquery seperate it from angular, you can use lodash to define your own jquery function and call then in angular

Answer (score 0):

To create a layout template:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Or flexible routing with nested views:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router