# angularJS - ng-model is not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

After working on some tutorials about `AngularJS` I'm now writing my very first example app on my own. I started with showing a very simple list of employees, which works fine. Now I wanted to add a simple text filter, like I learned in a tutorial.

I added an input with `ng-model="filterText"` and `| filter: filterText` to the list in my html as well as `$scope.filterText = null;` to my angularJS controller.

When I now enter anything to the input, nothing happens. When I set a `filterText` value directly to my `AngularJS` controller, the filter is working, so there has to be a problem with updating the value of `textFilter`.

What can I do to get it working? I have already searched for a solution, but nothing helps.

**My html:**

```
<div class="container main-frame" ng-app="Employees" ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="init()">

<div id="searchbox">
    <label>Filter: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
</div>

<div id="emplist">

    <h2>Employees</h2>

    <p>
        <ul id="emps">
            <li ng-repeat="mitarbeiter in results | filter: filterText">
                # {{mitarbeiter.id}} - <strong>{{mitarbeiter.name}}</strong>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </p>

</div>
```

**My angularJS:**

```
var app = angular.module('Employees', []);

app.controller("mainController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.filterText = null;

    $scope.init = function(){

        jsonObject = eval(jsonfunction("parameters"));

        angular.forEach(jsonObject, function (mitarbeiter, key) {

            $scope.results.push(mitarbeiter);

        });

    }

})
```

**EDIT:**

According to the answer of **[NidhishKrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076676/1575570)**:

In firebug my jsonObject looks like the following:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Jane"},{"id":3,"name":"Peter"}]
```

I changed the working solution with this jsonObject and it is still working fine, so this should not be the problem...

Further information: I'm working in VS 2013 debugging mode with a web api 2 controller, which gets the data of a sql database. My jsonfunction is nothing else but an ajax request to the controller.

**EDIT2:**

When I don't use `eval()`, nothing changes. I successfully get my list, but I can't use the filter... here's my Ajax request:

```
function jsonfunction(par) {

    $.ajax({

        url: url + par,

        async: false,

        success: function (data) {

            json = data;

        },

        headers: getSecurityHeaders()

    });

    return json;

}
```

The answer is formatted to JSON within my `WebApiConfig.cs`. There couldn't be any error...

Comment: jsonfunction is not defined.....

Comment: Oh... jsonfunction is working fine. The list is showing up. I just didn't add the code to this question. jsonfunction gives me a well formatted json object. I'm already working with this function for a longer time, so there should be no problem. 

I just can't use the filter.

Comment: just take a look at my answer, jsonfunction  return an json as shown there,everything is working fine, even filter all working fine

Comment: hope so you have understood it......

Comment: Why do you need `eval` anyway? It's never a good idea to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonObject` javascript variable should get some datas like as shown below

```
jsonObject=[{id:1,name:'Jessey'},
            {id:2,name:'John'},
            {id:3,name:'Mathew'},
            {id:4,name:'Sunny'}];
```

But in your code `jsonfunction` is not defined, and what's the purpose of evaluating that using eval instead we need to return a `JSON` then everything even filter all will works fine as expected

```
jsonObject = eval(jsonfunction("parameters"));
```

Also don't mix up `JQuery` with `AngularJS`, Since its not a Good Practice, Please read - **[Using Jquery UI plugin with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053457/using-jquery-ui-plugin-with-angular/23053506#23053506)**

For `AJAX` `AngularJS` itself provides [**$http**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

**[A Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/36/)**

**EDIT 1**

```
$scope.init = function()
{
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/someUrl'
             }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (mitarbeiter, key) {
                $scope.results.push(mitarbeiter);
            });
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still confused. I edited my question, it would be great if you could have a look. My jsonObject works in your example, too... could there be any problem with angularJS in connection to my project setup?

Comment: can you show me your ajax call which is defined which you says that returns a JSON

Comment: Edited my question again. My request without eval() changes nothing. I posted my Ajax request above. There shouldn't be a problem I think.

Comment: @Fabi one advice...don't mix up jquery with angular, its not a Good Practice , for ajax Angular itself provides [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: @Fabi check out my edit.....make up a promise by bringing the angular loop into on success block of ajax call

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I tried to use $http instead of my ajax request, but now my $scope.results look like [object Object], [object Object],... and my list is not shown anymore... so is there a problem with my data? data in success(data) gives me a correct json?

Comment: @Fabi its fine try out `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.results));` instead of `console.log($scope.results)`, check if ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50673/discussion-between-nidhishkrishnan-and-fabi)