# Materialize: ERROR TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, user-interface, jquery-ui, materialize

I'm trying to use date picker from the Materialize CSS but I'm getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

My jquery:^3.3.1

Materialize-CSS:^0.100.2

Angular: 7.0.0

I'm getting the same error with both date picker and time picker.

But I'm able to use rest of Jquery code but these two won't work.

Comment: `.datepicker()` is a part of jQuery UI. Which jQuery UI are you loading in addition to those listed above?

Comment: "@types/jquery": "^3.3.22", This is the only other jquery I have. It is provided by angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Jquery UI plugin with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053457/using-jquery-ui-plugin-with-angular)

Comment: But I'm using Angular 7 not AngularJS

Comment: This is for 6, but it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421917/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-angular-6

Comment: @Twisty Neah it didn't work and by the way, I'm able to use rest of jquery code in my project without adding any import.

Comment: You may consider editing the tags and adding some tags for Angular. The message you encountered means there is an error upstream that is causing jQuery UI Library not to load, but you've included it, or you have not included it.

Comment: Adding tags like what? And is there any way to check whether it's included or not.

Comment: You should stop using jQuery with Angular and use https://material.angular.io/

Comment: @Oen44 so should i uninstall jquery?

Comment: Yes. You don't need jQuery, everything can be done with JS and Angular. It's bad practice to use jQuery with Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the **ngx-materialize** module and then used the datepicker according to their documentation. It worked without any error. I think the best way to use materialize-css with Angular2+ is with ngx-materialize rather than using materialize-css directly.